# Why does Hadoop open file succeeds when name-node is up but data-node is down?

Tags: hadoop

I have a doubt on Hadoop. I have a system where name-node is up but data-node is down . I see that when I make a call to open file it is  successful .  Now is this not wrong ? I think this as wrong because the Hadoop name node never stores file data  but it is the data-node which is meant to store the information . So in my view open file should be successful only when atleast 1 data node is up .

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you tried to open some file on HDFS, at very first time your request takes help from name-node to locate the blocks, after getting the location client establishes the connection with node directly, so after connection is successful then even though name-node fails it doesn't impact the operation as it is not involving it.

And if your request knows the location of the file on HDFS, then it even doesn't need to go name-node, it can establish data-node connection directly.

But in vise versa, if data-node is down, while name-node is working as your all data relies on data-node not name-node, so ideally your data request should fail, and even though you are getting data then I suggest to check your local cache.(Try clearing local cache)